# click of a submit button on any website using Google extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

On the click of a submit button on any website eg. Amazon, I want a .html to  be triggered using google extension. please let me know if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed execute scripts on (almost) any page using [content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) that can manipulate the DOM, allowing you to add an `onsubmit` event listener to a form (more reliable than `onclick` on a button as it is fired however the form is submitted - e.g. hitting `ENTER`).

What exactly do you mean you "want a .html to be triggered"? Triggered in what way? If you want to open another tab when this happens, you can do this using [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to tell your background page to do this for you using the [chrome.tab.create](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-create) API method.

Comment: But you have to use `.addEventListener()` in order not to overwrite the event listener of the website itself.

Comment: @ComFreek I'm assuming that's an additional tip and not a concern as I totally agree. I just assume everyone uses [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) these days, as they should ;) If you want to prevent the form from submitting you can call [event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault), or [event.stopImmediatePropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopImmediatePropagation) if you don't want any other existing event listeners to be called after yours.